# How to output all checkbox value

Tags: php, forms, validation, checkbox, output

hello please help me i have a problem outputting all the values of  checkbox it outputs only one i need to show all the checked checkbox and output them please help me here is the code it only shows one whenever i checked them all i need this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cake Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cakeform.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        $nameErr = $addErr = $phoneErr = $scake  = $flavorcake = $fill = "";
$name = $address = $phone =  $rcake = $fillr = $cakeflavor = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
     $phoneErr = "Gender is required";
   } else {
     $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['SelectedCake'])){
       $x=$_POST['SelectedCake'];

   }
   if(isset($_POST['CakeFlavor'])){
       $y=$_POST['CakeFlavor'];

   }
   if(isset($_POST['Filling'])){
       $z=$_POST['Filling'];

   }
   if(empty($x)){
       $scake='Select one Cake';


   }else{

       $rcake= $x;

   }
    if(empty($y) OR $y == 'Flavor'){
       $flavorcake='Select one flavor';


   }else{

       $cakeflavor= $y;

   }
   if(empty($z)){
       $fill='Select at least one Fillings';


   }else{
       foreach($z as $item){
           $fillr=$item;

       }


   }



}
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


    ?>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="cont_order">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Make your own Cake</legend>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
        <h4>Select size for the Cake:</h4>
        <input type="radio" name="SelectedCake" value="Round6">Round cake 6" - serves 8 people</br>
        <input type="radio" name="SelectedCake" value="Round8">Round cake 8" - serves 12 people</br>    
        <input type="radio" name="SelectedCake" value="Round10">Round cake 10" - serves 16 people</br>  
        <input type="radio" name="SelectedCake" value="Round12">Round cake 12" - serves 30 people</br>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $scake;?></span>        
        <h4>Select a Cake Flavor: </h4>
        <select name="CakeFlavor">
            <option value="Flavor" selected="selected">Select Flavor</option>
            <option value="Carrot" >Carrot</option>
            <option value="Chocolate" >Chocolate</option>
            <option value="Banana" >Banana</option>
            <option value="Red Velvet" >Red Velvet</option>
            <option value="Strawberry" >Strawberry</option>
            <option value="Vanilla" >Vanilla</option>
            <option value="Combo" >Combo</option>
        </select>
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $flavorcake;?></span>
        <h4>Select Fillings:</h4>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Filling[]" value="Cream"/>Cream</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Filling[]" value="Fudge"/>Fudge</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Filling[]" value="Ganache"/>Ganache</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Filling[]" value="Hazelnut"/>Hazelnut</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Filling[]" value="Mousse"/>Mousse</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="Filling[]" value="Pudding"/>Pudding</label><br>
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $fill;?></span>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_order">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Details</legend>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
        <br>
        <label for="address">Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address"><span class="error">*<?php echo $addErr;?></span>
        <br>
        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><span class="error">*<?php echo $phoneErr;?></span><br>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submitted" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="cont_order">
        <?php

            echo $name.'<br>';
            echo $address.'<br>';
            echo $phone.'<br>';
            echo $rcake.'<br>';
            echo $cakeflavor.'<br>';
            echo $fillr.'<br>';


        ?>

        </div>
        </div>


        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fact is, you accept a list for filling.
In your code you do this :

```
foreach($z as $item){
    $fillr=$item;
}
```

Replace it by :

```
$fillr = '';
foreach($z as $item){
    $fillr .= '- ' . $item . '<br/>';
}
```

It should work better.

---

For comment :

```
#so let's say $z is an array :

$z = [1,2,3,4];

#then you say, for each element of the array as you will call $item, I do something

foreach($z as $item){
    $fillr=$item; #here you say : for each element of $z (1,2,3,4), I put this value into $fillr.
}

#so let's do the loop together.
# First pass, $item == 1, so $fillr == 1.
# Second pass, $item == 2, so $fillr == 2.
# ...
# Last pass, $item == 4, so $fillr == 4.

# so then when you show $fillr it's the last item of the list (here 4).


# using PHP, .= means concatenate.
# for instance :
$a = "hello ";
$a .= "world";
echo $a;

> hello world


So basically, what I'm doing is :
Having an empty string I'll call $fillr.
For every element of the list,
  Append "the_element plus a <br/>" to $fillr

so then when you output $fillr it looks sexy.


Do you get it bud?
```

Comment: please explain it to me the more simpler way y your code works please refractor ur code to mek it more understanding to me what does .= do?? slight difference and it works please explain it to me easier im a newbie thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var_dump($_POST['Filling']);
```

Or just this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['Filling'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Filling'] as $check) {
            echo $check;     
    }
}
?>
```

Tell me if it works =)